# how can i post data in Codeigniter using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How can i post data in Codeigniter using Ajax, am so confused this is the first time i do ajax and Codeigniter together 
here is my ajax code

i tried to send the data to the controller method ;

This is my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#register_form').submit(function(evt){

var postData = $(this).serialize();


$.ajax({
url: baseURL+"admin/Products/add_product",
type:'post',
data:{productData:postData},
success:function(data){

}

});


});

});
```

this is my form

```
<?php $attribute = array( 'id'=>'register_form','form-horizontal'); ?>





 <?php echo form_open('admin/products/add_product',$attribute); ?>


<?php  echo form_label('product title'); ?>
 <?php echo form_input($data_product_title); ?>
<h6 style="color: red" class="require_error">this filed is required</h6>


<?php  echo form_label('product description'); ?>
 <?php echo form_textarea($data_product_description); ?>
 <h6 style="color: red" class="require_error">this filed is required</h6>

 <?php echo form_label('product price'); ?>
 <?php echo form_input($data_product_price); ?>
 <h6 style="color: red" class="require_error">this filed is required</h6>
 <?php echo form_label('product quantity'); ?>
 <?php echo form_input($data_product_quantity); ?>
<h6  style="color: red" class="require_error">this filed is required</h6>

 <?php echo form_submit($data_3); ?>


   <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: And what is the result? What is the expected result? What debugging have you done? Checked your Javascript console? Checked the network traffic?

Comment: Did you get any error? if you have an error then you can try by disabling CSRF in config.php file.

Comment: so far so good, but we don't know what your controller (and eventually model) looks like. please edit your question adding the `add_product()` function of the controller `products` and any related model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Your `ajax` script should be like this : , make sure your `URL` is correct*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#register_form').submit(function(evt){
    var postData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url : baseURL+"admin/Products/add_product",
      type:'post',
      data: postData,
      success:function(data)
      {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  evt.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

In your `add_product` method get `post` values like this :

```
public function add_product()
{
   print_r($this->input->post()); // to print all post values
   exit;
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: is this answer helpful to you?

Comment: pls also response to this answer also whether it is helpful or not

Answer (score -2):

```
`$('#add').click(function() {
        var form_data = {
           subject_name: $('#subject_name').val(),
           section: $('#section').val(),
           grade: $('#grade').val()enter code here
        };
        $.ajax({
           url:"<?php echo site_url('ViewCourses/SavingData');?>",
           type:'POST',
           data: form_data,
              success: function(msg) {
                if (msg == 'Yes')
                   document.location.reload(true);
                 else if (msg == 'No')
                   document.location.reload(true);
                 else
                    $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + msg+'</div>');
             }
         });
      return false;
});`
```

## add Its Button Id Pe Use Of  Onclick Function For Submit values With Ajax

form_data All Form Fields Of the Form

Comment: I don't see _any_ relation between this and the question.